# Pandas pivot value are merged

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Hi have data like below

```
Time                  qty
2021-07-23 02-06-49  0.02
2021-07-23 02-06-51  0.02
2021-07-23 02-06-53  2
2021-07-23 02-06-53  0.032
2021-07-23 02-06-54  2.842
2021-07-23 02-06-54  0.025
2021-07-23 02-06-55  0.02
2021-07-23 02-06-57  1.742
2021-07-23 02-06-57  0.395
```

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Time'],values=['qty'],aggfunc=np.sum)

print(df)
```

result like below

```
Time                    qty
2021-07-23 02-06-49     0.02
2021-07-23 02-06-51     0.02
2021-07-23 02-06-53     2.000000000.03200000
2021-07-23 02-06-54     2.842000000.02500000
2021-07-23 02-06-55     0.02
2021-07-23 02-06-57     1.742000000.39500000
```

I want the sum of **qty** value

Comment: Your result is weird... Can you update your post with the output of `df.info()`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output, it seems to me that "qty" a "string" dtype. Try forcing it to be a "float" and try again:

```py
df = df.astype({"qty": "float"})
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Time'], values=['qty'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Time', as_index=False)['qty'].sum()
                  Time    qty
0  2021-07-23 02-06-49  0.020
1  2021-07-23 02-06-51  0.020
2  2021-07-23 02-06-53  2.032
3  2021-07-23 02-06-54  2.867
4  2021-07-23 02-06-55  0.020
5  2021-07-23 02-06-57  2.137
```

Comment: thanks buddy,
i have a multiple Colum like qty, price i want to qty sum what can i do...?

Comment: And the other columns are dropped?

Comment: I updated my answer to compute sum only on `qty` column.

Comment: still i have the same result

 <
                       Time                                                  qty
0    2021-07-23 03-03-42                                         0.32320000
1    2021-07-23 03-03-47                                         0.65470000
2    2021-07-23 03-03-52                               1.532000000.04430000
>